# Unable to run yum update

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I tried to run yum update to start working with yum tool, when I tried to run

```
yum update
```

and got an error

After I saw few forums advises I already disable ipv6, firewalld and set dns server to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Output of yum update:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed connect to mirrorlist.centos.org:80; Operation now in progress"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue. Verify `/etc/resolv.conf` change and maybe `yum clean all`?

Comment: Other ideas... use `host`` to make sure you can resolve that URI. You behind a proxy? SElinux? Other firewall.

Comment: My  DNS is configured... I checked my proxy setting in my win computer and I’m not using it. I have internet connection and it all looks good so I really don’t understand what I’m doing wrong...(I am using virtualbox with cantos image)

Answer (score 0):

Most of this cases is because you did a command:

```
yum clean all
```

or anything that causes a corruption or wrong pointing of repos in the /etc/yum.repos.d/

Normally, it should just be ok, but sometimes it results to corruption of yum such as the following as I tried to clean now one of the server yum repo.
[image]
I encountered this error multiple times in the 9 servers that I handled. You can check your repos at /etc/yum.repos.d/. You should be able to see this:
[image]

If you can't resolve it by checking all .repo files, backup all your .repo and download the following files and upload it to your /etc/yum.repos.d:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WsJ1e8stj76JWJi-6IHQ1DVTmM7OsYzW
[image]

This will be the result afterwards:
[image]

This is really a problem that causes you a lot of headache with a simple solution. I hope that this will really truly help you.